# How to use routes in two different components - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

[image: Application dashboard]

I am creating an application using ReactJS. I am using react router v4 from `react-router-dom`.

I have written routes in index.js file.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Viewport} />
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Rest of the application in Viewport.js file.

```
    return (
        <div className="">
            <Sidebar navigation={this.viewport} />
            <HeaderBanner user={this.props.user} />
            <div className="center-panel">
                //todo
                //Can I use router here?
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

After user login's, I am rendering Viewport which contains Sidebar and header bar by default. Based on the item click in the sidebar navigation, I need to render components dynamically. As of now, if I write anything in the place of todo, it renders only that component for the complete browser window.
Is there any way to use routers in multiple places of the application? If yes, how can I implement it? If no, what's the best solution? 
As far as I have seen, routers will be stacked at one place in the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you can use the Route there. Check docs of Switch in react-router-dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed a tutorial on youtube recently which was very useful

So I took some of it and applied it to your setup

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Viewport} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>


import { NavLink, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class Viewport extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Side-bar">
          <NavLink
            activeClassName="active"
            to={`${this.props.match.url}/sub-page-name-1`}>Sub Page 1</NavLink>
          <NavLink
            activeClassName="active"
            to={`${this.props.match.url}/sub-page-name-2`}>Sub Page 2</NavLink>
          <NavLink
            activeClassName="active"
            to={`${this.props.match.url}/sub-page-name-3`}>Sub Page 3</NavLink>
        </div>
        <HeaderBanner user={this.props.user} />
        <div className="center-panel">
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/sub-page-name-1`} component={SubPagePanel1} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/sub-page-name-2`} component={SubPagePanel2} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/sub-page-name-3`} component={SubPagePanel3} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I removed `Switch` as well because I didn't use it for my sub pages... :-S

> **Update**:  Have created a repo showing a working example of sub page content

https://github.com/PocketNinjaDesign/so-sub-routes-answer

Comment: Could you please share me the link to youtube video? I need to explore more about this!

Comment: This solution didn't work. It renders only that particular Route component to the entire browser window

Comment: @Nandeesh Have added a repo link showing an example of React Router 4 with sub page content, hopefully that answers your question :-)

Comment: @Nandeesh hows it going for you there.  Did that answer your question?

Comment: I just did as you mentioned.. I started server and everything works fine in your code. If I implement the same thing in mine, I am not getting reference to "this.props.match.url". I simply hardcoded to "/dashboard/navigation-1" even that doesn't work.

Comment: Is there anything at the start that could be an issue? Are you literally copying the same React Router blocks elements in there that I created or is there anything different about yours...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `<Routes>` in as many places as you want. `<Router>` components are the ones you can only use once.